# How to calculate percentages of sum of sub-arrays so that their sum is strictly 100 using C# decimal

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, decimal, percentage

Let's say I have an array of integers. Lets logically divide it into just two parts for simplification.

Let's say `total sum` of all elements of array is `2860800`.

Let's say sum of all elements of `left half` is `2834387`.

Let's say sum of all elements of `right half` is `26413`.

Now calculating left half's percentage by `100m * leftHalfSum / totalSum` gives `99.07672678970917225950782998`.

Similarly, right half's percentage by `100m * rightHalfSum / totalSum` is `0.9232732102908277404921700224`.

Now, if I add these two percentages in Visual Studio's Watch, it shows me `100`. But if I add these in `Calculator` app in Windows, it gives me `100.0000000000000000000000000024`, which is correct.

Basically, I want `100-leftHalfPercentage` to be strictly equal to `rightHalfPercentage` and vice-versa. If I do `100-leftHalfPercentage` in Watch, it gives me `0.92327321029082774049217002`. Notice that it is exactly the same as `rightHalfPercentage` but the last two digits `24` are missing.

Thanks.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @L.B These are *not* floating point numbers, though (note the `m` after 100).

Comment: Guys, I know why this is happening. :) I need a good workaround solution which keeps `100-leftHalfPercentage` strictly equal to `rightHalfPercentage` and vice-versa.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Of course they are floating point. Just base 10 floating point, and not base 2.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but we don't know types of `leftHalfSum`  and `rightHalfSum` ?

Comment: Can you add actual code example?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Numbers of the type `Decimal` are also floating point numbers. You can represent some numbers exactly using the `Decimal` type, but some numbers can't be represented exactly using any numeric type. Consider for example numbers like `1/3` or pi.

Comment: @Guffa: This is for anybody interested in theory or history, not modern practical applications: 1/3 is represented exactly by the SETUN computer, built in Moscow University in 1958. It used radix 3, with digits -1, 0, and 1. See [this page](http://www.computer-museum.ru/english/setun.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers that you have calculated are correct, i.e. they represent their percentages with the same degree of precision.

If you want their sums to be exactly 100, then you have to pick one of the values to be less exact. The value that you choose to sacrifice would simply be calculated by subtracting all the other values from 100.

For example, having three equal groups calculated with one decimals would give you `33.3%` for each, giving you a sum of `99.9%`. To make the sum `100%` you would sacrifice the correctness for one group and calculate it as `100 - 33.3 - 33.3 = 33.4`.

Answer (score 2):

Decimals have a maximum precision of 28-29 significant digits ([Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). The full result of your calculation would be 30 digits long, to much for a decimal! That's why the last two digits are omitted.

If your result would be larger (a total sum of 10.000 instead of 100 for example) even more digits would be omitted.

The difference is probably caused by something internal and would probably need some inspection of the compiled code by someone more knowledgeable than me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing why the addition of both percentages result in 100 in Watch.